# Swap two list classes from different lists with each other

Tags: jquery, list, function, swap, items

I want to swap elements from two different lists. So if I select something on the left list and on the right list they need to swap.

It currently looks like this:
Html:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li value="1" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 1</li>
    <li value="2" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 2</li>
    <li value="3" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 3</li>
    <li value="4" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 4</li>
    <li value="5" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li value="1" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 1</li>
    <li value="2" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 2</li>
    <li value="3" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 3</li>
    <li value="4" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 4</li>
    <li value="5" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
var testClickSort1 ='';
var testClickSort2 ='';

$(function() {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

$("#sortable2").sortable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();

$("#sortable1 li").on('click',function(){
       // $("#testClickSort1").html($(this).attr('value'));
        testClickSort1 = $(this).attr('value'); 
        test();
});

$("#sortable2 li").on('click',function(){
       // $("#testClickSort2").html($(this).attr('value'));
        testClickSort2 = $(this).attr('value');
        test();
});
});

 function test(){ 
      if ((testClickSort1 != "") && (testClickSort2 != "")) {
         alert ("test: " + testClickSort1 + '' +  testClickSort2);
         //function to swap testclicksort1 with testclicksort2
         testClickSort1 = '';
         testClickSort2 = '';
}   
}
```

It can be viewed here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qkCcS/26/

Now I need to know what the function is to swap testclicksort1 with testclicksort2.

Thanks in advance.

Greets,

Wouter

Comment: Why are you asking same question again and again ?. Wasn't it answered first time ?

Comment: No it wasn't and I was using different code in there. I updated the topic but it ended on the bottom somewhere so bit useless. Wasn't expecting any reactions. Now I'm closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do something like this:

```
$(".connectedSortable").on('click','li', function () {
        /* make sure only one selected at a  time in a list*/
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected')
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        switchSelectedItems()
 }); 

function switchSelectedItems() {
    var $selected = $('.selected');
    /* make sure there is a pair*/
    if ($selected.length == 2) {
        $selected.each(function () {
            $(this).after($selected.not(this).clone().removeClass('selected'));
        }).remove()
    }
}
```

What this code does is make a clone of each of the selected items, places that after it's match in other list, then removes the originals

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qkCcS/38/)**</kbd>

Comment: Great start, looks good! But what if i want to switch the elements back? Now it's just a one time action from the left list to the right or from the right list to the left. Is this possible?

Comment: of course it's possible. You could store the element ID's and use for undo if needed

Comment: Maybe I ask a bit too much but I'm really noob at javascript and need to fix this for a school project (app prototype). Could you provide me some example? If not, it's okay and then i'm going to try to solve it myself! You already helped me a lot so thanks man!

Comment: well what you want poses more questions like based on what events? You had nothing in the UI but 2 lists. WHen you only ask how to switch...that's usually what you get...not a complete app

Comment: Hahaha, no i dont ask you for an app. I only want to know how to switch list items back and forth in this list. I already coded the app. This is just some functionality i need. But with this example i can switch the list items just one time. If they are switched and i click on them again they need to be able to switch again. For that piece i'm asking an example!

Comment: OK... I forgot to delegate the click handler change `on()` to `$(".connectedSortable").on('click','li', function () {` ...will be able to click them after they are moved....http://jsfiddle.net/qkCcS/38/

Comment: You are the man! Happy christmas man! I owe you a million haha. Can't vote your answer up! Otherwise I would have done it!